# Bert model splits words by its own

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am tokenizing the input words using bert model.
The code is :

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-cased',do_lower_case = False)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased", add_pooling_layer=False, output_hidden_states=True, output_attentions=True)

marked_text =  text + " [SEP]"
    tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(marked_text)
    indexed_tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_text)
    print(tokenized_text)
    print(indexed_tokens)
```

The model I used is from HuggingFace.

My goal is to print the embedded vectors of all words Bert model has, so I searched and found that this model has 119296 tokens available.

I don't know this number of the tokens is reason, but the model splits the words by its own, which is unwanted for me.

for example,

```
only -> [only]
ONLY -> [ON,L,Y]

stradivarius -> ['St', '##radi', '##vari', '##us']
```

Is this natural Bert thing or I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: A token is not a word. Tokens are bits and pieces of words. What is considered a token or not entirely depends on the training process of the language model or whatever. It is fully expected that tokens aren't 1:1 with words. If you look up how tokens work with ChatGPT, for example, there are many official pages explaining why tokens do not correspond to whole words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. Bert uses a so-called [wordpiece](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tokenizer_summary#wordpiece) subword tokenizer as a compromise for meaningful embeddings and acceptable memory consumption between a character-level (small vocabulary) and a word-level tokenizer (large vocabulary).

A common approach to retrieve word embeddings from a subword-based model is to take the mean of the respective tokens. The code below shows you have you can retrieve the word embeddings (non-contextualized and contextualized) by taking the mean. It uses a fasttokenizer to utilize the methods of the [BatchEncoding](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.BatchEncoding) object.

```py
import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast, BertModel

t = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-cased')
# whole model
m = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased")
# token embedding layer
embedding_layer = m.embeddings.word_embeddings

sample_sentence = 'This is an example with token-embeddings and word-embeddings'
encoded = t([sample_sentence])
# The BatchEncoding object allows us to map the token back to the string indices
print(*[(token_id, encoded.token_to_chars(idx)) for idx, token_id in enumerate(encoded.input_ids[0])], sep="\n")
# And we can also check the mapping of word to token indices
print(*[(word, encoded.word_to_tokens(idx)) for idx, word in enumerate(sample_sentence.split())], sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
(101, None)
(10747, CharSpan(start=0, end=4))
(10124, CharSpan(start=5, end=7))
(10151, CharSpan(start=8, end=10))
(14351, CharSpan(start=11, end=18))
(10169, CharSpan(start=19, end=23))
(18436, CharSpan(start=24, end=27))
(10136, CharSpan(start=27, end=29))
(118, CharSpan(start=29, end=30))
(10266, CharSpan(start=30, end=32))
(33627, CharSpan(start=32, end=35))
(13971, CharSpan(start=35, end=39))
(10107, CharSpan(start=39, end=40))
(10111, CharSpan(start=41, end=44))
(12307, CharSpan(start=45, end=49))
(118, CharSpan(start=49, end=50))
(10266, CharSpan(start=50, end=52))
(33627, CharSpan(start=52, end=55))
(13971, CharSpan(start=55, end=59))
(10107, CharSpan(start=59, end=60))
(102, None)
('This', TokenSpan(start=1, end=2))
('is', TokenSpan(start=2, end=3))
('an', TokenSpan(start=3, end=4))
('example', TokenSpan(start=4, end=5))
('with', TokenSpan(start=5, end=6))
('token-embeddings', TokenSpan(start=6, end=8))
('and', TokenSpan(start=8, end=9))
('word-embeddings', TokenSpan(start=9, end=13))
```

To retrieve the word embeddings:

```
with torch.inference_mode():
  token_embeddings = embedding_layer(encoded.convert_to_tensors("pt").input_ids).squeeze()
  # we need the attention mechanism of the whole model to get the contextualized token representations
  contextualized_token_embeddings = m(**encoded.convert_to_tensors("pt")).last_hidden_state.squeeze()

def fetch_word_embeddings(sample_sentence:str, encoded, embeddings:torch.Tensor) -> dict[str,torch.Tensor]:
  word_embeddings = {}
  for idx, word in enumerate(sample_sentence.split()):
    start, end = encoded.word_to_tokens(idx)
    word_embeddings[word] = embeddings[start:end].mean(dim=0)
  return word_embeddings

word_embeddings = fetch_word_embeddings(sample_sentence, encoded, token_embeddings)
contextualized_word_embeddings = fetch_word_embeddings(sample_sentence, encoded, contextualized_token_embeddings)
print(word_embeddings["token-embeddings"])
print(contextualized_word_embeddings["token-embeddings"])
```

Output:

```
tensor([ 1.2455e-02, -3.8478e-02,  8.0834e-03, ..., -1.8502e-02,  1.1511e-02, -6.5307e-02])
tensor([-5.1564e-01, -1.6266e-01, -3.9420e-01, ..., -5.9969e-02,  3.0784e-01, -3.4451e-01])
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a normal behaviour, since tokens can be parts of words, see here for instance: https://help.openai.com/en/articles/4936856-what-are-tokens-and-how-to-count-them.

OK, this links says that tokens are indeed parts of word, but does not explain **why** it is so.

Not knowing the deep technical explanation, I have 2 hypothesis:

- BERT aims at encoding into a fixed-length vector, whether the input is a phrase or a paragraph. Words are a human concept: for BERT, tokens may be a more relevant one to achieve this embedding.
- splitting text in tokens smaller than words may be especially size-saving in multilingual models, since a same token can be found in several languages. "vari" for instance can belong to "varie" or "avarie", in French, "varied" in English, etc...

These are just hypotheses, anybody with a better knowledge of the subject is welcome to correct them!